# How to call a method specific to a C++ subclass

Tags: c++, types

Hi I have a `Tour` class and `GuidedTour` which extends `Tour`.
I'm doing following on my code :

```
Tour* t;

if(x) {

    t = new Tour(...);
}
else {

    t = new GuidedTour(...);
}
```

However when I do the following,

```
t->getDate();
```

(`getDate()` is specific to `GuidedTour` class)

I get the following error

```
'class Tour' has no member named 'getDate'
```

How can I call this method?

Comment: Shouldn't a `Tour` have a date also?

Comment: Just a matter of coding style: prefer using the structure if (special case) else (default case) instead of the inverse as you did.

Comment: If GuidedTour has a date, but not Tour, what do you think should happen when x is true and getDate is called? Either all tours have dates, or you need to redesign your use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here.  A syntactic one, which the other answers have taken stabs at getting around for you, and a design flaw which nobody has addressed.

The syntactic problem is caused by the fact that, indeed, `Tour` has no `getDate` method.  And yet you are trying to call this function:

```
Tour* t;
// ... MAGIC HAPPENS
t->getDate(); // ERROR
```

This code tells the compiler "I have a pointer to a Tour object.  Call the getDate() method on it."  But the compiler says, "Um, Tour doesn't have a getDate() method."

You know that the *dynamic* type of the object is actually a `GuidedTour`, but the compiler doesn't know that.  All the compiler knows is that `t` is a pointer to a `Tour`.

There are a number of ways to resolve this difference between what the compiler knows and what you know.

One is to make `getDate()` a member of `Tour` -- but if you wanted `getDate()` to be a member of `Tour` then you presumably would have designed it that way in the first place.

Another is to tell the compiler that you know something it doesn't know -- that `t` actually points to a `GuidedTour`.  You do that using `dynamic_cast`.  But if you know something the compiler doesn't know, it's usually *not* because the compiler is stupid, but because there's something wrong with your *design* -- and that's your second problem.  That's why I usually say that if you have a `dynamic_cast` in your program, you should take a closer look at your design because this is often indicative of a design flaw.  There are also potential performance considerations with using a `dynamic_cast` and, while they might be substantial, in my view they still aren't the main problem with `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: I think, the "you know more then the compiler" part would justify the use of `static_cast` (which succeeds within a class hierarchy). `dynamic_cast` says that the code has special treatment for specific sub-classes. Of course, it's much nicer to put the abstraction into the base-class using virtual or abstract methods and have the specialized behavior in the derived classes because that's really the point of deriving classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
virtual Date GetDate() { throw std::exception("unimplemented"); }
```

into class Tour and make GetDate virtual in GuidedTour.
You can also cast:

```
dynamic_cast<GuidedTour*>(t)->GetDate()
```

Comment: Better make that `if (GuidedTour * guidedTour = dynamic_cast<GuidedTour*>(t)) { ... guidedTour->GetDate() ...}`.

Comment: I assumed that it already is `if(x) { t->GetDate(); }` with same x as in the question.

Comment: @monnoroch: If you somehow know that the dynamic type is `GuidedTour` so that you don't need to check the result of `dynamic_cast`, then why waste time with a dynamic (rather than static) cast at all?

Comment: @Mike makes no sense to me, might still be the case with modifying some odd legacy code.

Comment: Although it will quick fix the specific problem, clearly the OP has a problem in his design.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you declared t as a Tour. 
Even though you instanciate it as a GuidedTour later on, Tour does not have a getDate() function, hence the error.
You can call it by casting it as a GuidedTour first :

```
GuidedTour *tAsGuidedTour = dynamic_cast<GuidedTour*>(t)
if (tAsGuidedTour != NULL)
{
   tAsGuidedTour->getDate();
}
```

EDIT: you can read http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ for a better understanding

Answer (score -1):

Sample:

```
#include"stdio.h"
class Tour
{
public:
    Tour(){}
    ~Tour(){}
    int getDate()
    {
        printf("Func Display!\n");
        return 0;
    }
private:
    ///
};
class GuidedTour:public Tour
{
public:
    GuidedTour(){}
    ~GuidedTour(){}
private:
    ///
};
int main()
{
    int x;
    Tour *t;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x) t=new Tour;
    else t=new GuidedTour;
    t->getDate();
    return 0;
}
```

maybe you extended the private part of class 'Tour'.

Comment: The OP said `getDate()` is specific to `GuidedTour`, it's not in the `Tour` base class.